# Permission denied in Geolocater while asking user permission

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am trying to get the user current location and pass its position to camera starting position of Google maps. I have also added in my Android manifest file but when I try to run the app, it throws an exception linked in the picture below.

[image]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: please put your full code  that get current location

Comment: check the status of the permission and if the permission status is denied, ask the user for a permission.. use this package it makes it easier to handle permissions https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: void locateCurrentpos() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    current_position = position;

    // As the location comes with Geopoint with lattitude and longitude
    LatLng lat_position = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude); 


    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(target: lat_position, zoom:14);
    new_google_map_controller_for_saving.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

  }